# How to print data which is inside an array which is in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, ejs

I have a MongoDB database in which I created a schema which has ebook subjects which is an array of multiple subjects, each subject is an array of ebooks inside them so ebookTopic -> [ebookSubjects -> [ebooks] ].

For example, we have an array of subjects like math, English, and science each subject is an array of ebooks.

```
ebookSubs: [
  {
    ebook_Topic: Math,
    ebook_TopicImg: String,
    ebooks: [
      {
        ebook_Name: SL arora book,
        ebook_Link: String,
      },
      {
        ebook_Name: Henry book,
        ebook_Link: String,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    ebook_Topic: Science,
    ebook_TopicImg: String,
    ebooks: [
      {
        ebook_Name: String,
        ebook_Link: String,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

My ejs file looks like this which is just wrong

```
//This is supposed to print cards
<section id="sem_cards">
  <div>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
      <% foundEbook.forEach(function(ebook_Sub){ %> <%
      bookSubs.forEach(function(Subjects){ %>
      <a href="">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img
              src="Images/<%= Subjects.ebook_TopicImg %>"
              class="card-img-top" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h1 class="card-title"><%= Subjects.ebook_Topic %></h1>
              <p class="card-text mb-3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Repudiandae, cum officia. Molestias
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <small>Latest updated for 2023</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <% }) %> <% }) %>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am getting error that means I cant reach the objects, it says :
undefined on ejs line 5 saying forEach is undefined.

Comment: What's the exact error and what line is it on?

Comment: Please split your example, description and source code to make it more readable. (possiby by just placing the closing ```` on a new line).

Comment: can u please explain uptill what data you want to print or what should be the expected output??

Answer (score 0):

This seems off:

```
<% foundEbook.forEach(function(ebook_Sub){ %> 
<% bookSubs.forEach(function(Subjects){ %>
```

It should be something like:

```
<% foundEbook.forEach(function(ebook_Subs){ %>
<% ebook_Subs.forEach(function(Subjects){ %>
```